# Haskell data constructor name with hyphen

Tags: haskell, types

I wish to have a data constructor with a name including some hyphens like this:

```
data D = The-First |  The-Second deriving (Ord, Eq, Show, Read)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Should begin with using lowercase. Uppercase is mainly used for data types.

Comment: Nope, this is simply not possible in Haskell. Variables / constructors can only contain letters, underscores and prime symbols, hyphens are not allowed. Why do you think you need a hyphen there? What's wrong with `TheFirst` or `The_First`? If your actual use case isn't more complicated, it might also be worth considerung to simply use `Either Int Int`, then you don't need to define any constructors at all. — @CommuSoft: erm, no! Constructors _must_ in fact begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks! I just removed the Int but it is still not working. The actual use case is more complicated so I have to use hyphen to follow a specific naming convention. BTW, underscore is working perfectly so The_First is OK but The-First is has problematic.

Comment: Well, a naming convention that mandates hyphens is impossible to follow.

Comment: Hyphens aren't valid in identifiers in *any* widely used programming language that I can think of. Where did this naming convention come from? It certainly wasn't designed by a Haskell programmer and intended for Haskell code, and I doubt it was intended for code at all. Are you sure you're not trying to apply a naming convention intended for something else (e.g. filenames) to Haskell constructors, perhaps because you're using Show or Read instances to connect the two?

Comment: @Ben: Ahem... Lisp? ;)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I did not know that! To my regret, I have not yet learned a lisp. :)

Comment: @Ben yes this is a naming convention outside programming stuff. I think I have to write a function that maps the names on the data constructors to intended naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not allowed by the Haskell Standard. Quoting relevant parts of it:

From [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-120001.3):

> There are six kinds of names in Haskell: those for variables and
>   constructors denote values; those for type variables, type
>   constructors, and type classes refer to entities related to the type
>   system; and module names refer to modules. There are two constraints
>   on naming:
>
> 1.Names for variables and type variables are identifiers beginning with lowercase letters  or underscore; the other four kinds of names are identifiers beginning with uppercase letters.
>
> 2. An identifier must not be used as the name of a type constructor and a class in the same scope.

And from [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4):

> An identifier consists of a letter followed by zero or more letters,
>   digits, underscores, and single quotes.

Summary: Just get used to the CamelCase format. You will start liking it after some time. :)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I have to use hyphen to follow a specific naming convention.

Comment: @PHA What specific naming convention ? When you are using a language, it's best to adhere to the language's accepted conventions. And in your case, there is no way other than removing hyphen to make it typecheck.

Comment: @PHA It's probably easier to change your naming convention than the grammar of the Haskell language.

Answer (score 0):

well, I presume if one wanted it might be possible to use Template Haskell to accept expressions and generate constructor names (I've never used it, so I don't know if it can kick in at that point in the grammar). I wouldn't then know how to allow [The-First] and not [The - First], as they parse the same.

But really, using CamelCase or Camel_Case is so much better that you don't want to look at any other crazy options.